# How to relaunch current program in macOS with execl("/usr/bin/open"...)?

Tags: c, objective-c, macos, exec

I can successfully launch an app with

`execl("/usr/bin/open", "open", "/Applications/Foo.app", 0);`

But this doesn't work when I'm calling it inside Foo.app

I want my app to relaunch itself when it crashes and autoupdates.

Thanks!

Comment: How can your program do anything when it crashes? Are you catching a signal in a handler? What do you mean by “autoupdates”? How do you know your program is in `/Applications/Foo.app` rather than `/SomePathTheUserPicked/Foo.app`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, I'm catching a signal. My app must be in /Applications, it's enforced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open` won't start a second instance of your app if one is already running, it will simply make it the active app.

You can start a second instance of your app by executing the app bundle's executable:

```
excel("/Applications/Foo.app/Contents/MacOS/Foo", ...
```

While not the recommended way to launching a Cocoa app, I've been assured by Apple engineers that this will work. But be warned, you now have two instances of your app running, sharing the same `NSUserDefaults`, and other resources, so expect some strange behavior (or immediately terminate the first app through `exit()`).

Having said that, this probably isn't want you want to do.

First, you can't "detect a crash and take some action" as—by definition—your app has crashed. There are packages out there that will detect a crash and log information about it; look to a solution like that to restart your app.

As for updates, again I'd steer you towards a third-party solution like [Sparkle](https://sparkle-project.org). It handles quitting your old app, replacing it, and then launching the new one in a sane manner.

Finally, you can register your app as a "user agent" with `launchd` so that it gets automatically restarted if it quits.

Comment: Thanks a lot James. Yes, I call exit() immediately after execl().

Comment: Also, what about using "open -n" ?

Comment: `open -n` works too, but execing `open` to exec another app just seems like an unnecessary layer of complexity.